# Не соединяет результат двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Надо объединить результат с двух таблиц

```
(SELECT 0 as conversions, SUM(clicks) as clicks FROM general_report WHERE _offer_id = 1043 AND _aff_id = 9 AND (`date_time` BETWEEN '2017-05-24' AND '2017-05-24'))
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) as conversions, 0 as clicks FROM conversion_report WHERE _offer_id = 1043 AND _aff_id = 9 AND (DATE(conversion_time) BETWEEN '2017-05-24' AND '2017-05-24'))
```

На выходе получаю

```
+-------------+--------+
| conversions | clicks |
+-------------+--------+
|           0 |   1547 |
|          24 |      0 |
+-------------+--------+
```

А мне нужно

```
+-------------+--------+
| conversions | clicks |
+-------------+--------+
|          24 |   1547 |
+-------------+--------+
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Скорее всего на выходе вы даже две таблицы получаете. Вас не смущает `0 as conversions` в первом и `0 as clicks` во втором селектах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы объединяете 2 запроса. Первый выдаст строчку `0, 1547`, второй - `24, 0`, поэтому результат выполнения sql-запроса логичен. Сделайте так:

```
select sum(conversions), sum(clicks)
from
((SELECT 0 as conversions, clicks as clicks 
 FROM general_report 
 WHERE _offer_id = 1043 AND _aff_id = 9 
    AND (`date_time` BETWEEN '2017-05-24' AND '2017-05-24'))
 UNION ALL
(SELECT 1 as conversions, 0 as clicks 
 FROM conversion_report 
 WHERE _offer_id = 1043 AND _aff_id = 9 
    AND (DATE(conversion_time) BETWEEN '2017-05-24' AND '2017-05-24'))) t
```

Comment: Вот я балбес :)) большое спасибо, заработался видимо